# can Multicast receivers also act as multicast data generators?

Tags: ip, multicast

suppose I have 4 computers A B C and D. If B C and D are receiving multicast data from A, can one of them ...say B... can also send multicast data to others say A C and D?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, they'd just have to use the same multicast address to send. All computers should be subscribed to the multicast group anyway.